# Plupload script renaming files after upload

Tags: php, jquery, upload, plupload

I am using plupload (http://www.plupload.com) script and it's working ok but it renames the files after upload...

for example:
If i upload a file named: "some-thing.jpg" it will rename it in "something.jpg"

Is it posible disable this renaming of "minus sign"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the original upload.php file provided in the plupload examples then the renaming is most likely caused by this code:

```
// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '', $fileName);
```

You should modify that regular expression code to fit your file naming requirements.